# Incrementing a value in nested attributes in AWS Lambda and DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

This is my query to add a new field or increment a nested attribute

```
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_GAMES_TABLE, 
    Key: {
        id: gameId
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'set players.#player.#score = players.#player.#score + :s',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#player': playerId,
      '#score': 'score'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':s': 1
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
```

This is the error I get

```
{
  "message": "The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2020-05-21T03:03:14.328Z",
  "requestId": "Q04QEP1G3E2LAM43I04ADLM4IRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 27.814212380235393
}
```

My object looks like

```
{
  "id": "09e7a690",
  "players": {
    "M3EDJeHtoAMCLJg": [
      {
        "cardId": "1",
        "cardTitle": "test",
        "pun": "this is a pun"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the player with this ID exist? If not it will fail with this error message. You should probably add an intermediate step which creates the player with the given ID with `if_not_exists`. Have a look here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=938526

Comment: yep you are right. It helps to think in terms of a JavaScript object and once it clicked it all made sense

Comment: Perfect :) glad that the comment was helpful